# Could not get crash report in Crashlytics / fabric. Showing error : "It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below."

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

[image: Screenshot of fabric dashboard]

Crash reports are not generated in fabric/ crashlytics for my iOS application. An error (as given in screenshot) is being displayed on fabric dashboard.

As instructed by fabric I tried to search the given UUIDs in spotlight from the machine where the fabric mac app is installed.(where I create build of app.) but could not get any results. 
Also tried to search using terminal with command : `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>”` (as given in : http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/376834-missing-dsyms ) but could not get any results there also.

Anybody had this issue before ? Any workarounds to resolve this ?

Comment: So are you running the script in *Build Phases* which submits the `dsym`s to Crashlytics during a build?

Comment: yes. I am running a shell script in build phase which was copied while integrating fabric..

Comment: Might this help someone - [All you need to know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856414/crashlytics-does-not-show-crashes/40037060#40037060)

Answer (score 65):

I have after I complete the Fabric setup successfully into my app, the same issue,I tried every solution but the one that worked for me was:

1. Go to Project settings of the project and target and set **Debug Information Format** to **DWARF with dSYM File**

Set the current config
[image]

Comment: If I add Crashlytics via CocoaPods, do I have to set this in the `pods.xcodeproj` settings as well?

Answer (score 42):

You can get crash reports by generating dSYMs file for particular version of build and upload it on crashlytics.

Follow below steps to generate dSYMs file.

1. Go to **Window Menu -> Organizer** in Xcode.
2. Select the **right version of build** and click on the button **"Download Debug Symbols"** on the right panel
3. Right **Click on right version of build** and select show in Finder.
4. Select **.xcarchieve file** then right click on that and click on **Show Package contents**
5. Then **Go to **dSYMs** folder** and select **.dSYM file and compress that file**.
6. Now Final Step is to **upload compressed file on fabric**.

And then you can get crash report of build.

Comment: I have 3 archives with the build version specified by crashlytics. I tried uploading zipped dSYMs of all the 3, and after uploading each, it shows a message "The dSYM was successfully uploaded!". But the error is still there, even after refreshing the page.. :-(

Comment: I have also arise same issue.  I have fixed by logout and login into fabric.try it.May be help it.

Comment: from where did you logout and login ? mac app or web site ?

Comment: I have do it from website.

Comment: tried logout - login also after uploading. still not working. the error is still there.. :-(

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Tried uploading the dSym multiple times and log out and in nothing seems to be helping. Did anyone figure out the issue behind this ?

Comment: Before doing step 2, in the Organizer, select the version and then click on the "download dSYMs..." button on the right hand side.

Answer (score 22):

I got the answer finally :

I went into iTunes Connect > My Apps > Activity > Clicked on build missing dSYM  > Download dSYM.Once downloaded add .zip extension at end (not sure why .zip is not showing by apple) and was able to unzip it. In this folder I was able to find the missing dSYM requested by fabric, then  upload it to fabric.

it will take a few minutes to process a dSYM. In my case it took 24 hours to re-symbolicate crash report.

Comment: We're processing the uploaded dSYM(s). Please check back in a few minutes for the status.

Answer (score 14):

Considering the answers:

1. Go to **Window Menu -> Organizer** in Xcode.

> Now in the Organizer, select the version and then click on the "download dSYMs..." button on the right hand side.

2. Right **Click on right version of build** and select show in Finder.
3. Select **.xcarchieve file** then right click on that and click on **Show Package contents**
4. Then **Go to **dSYMs** folder** and select **.dSYM file and compress that file**.

> Remember to compress suitable **.dSYM** file, for instance:

[image]

[image]

5. Now Final Step is to **upload compressed file on fabric**.

While uploading the result is following:

[image]

If you do not have a build on your computer you can download dSYMS directly from itunesconnect:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For me the problem was solved when I unchecked `Include bitcode` when upload to AppStore or Export file.

[image]

Hopefully this will be resolved in the next Crashlytics update.

Comment: Super... I was trying to find the cause of the error from 3 consecutive days & nights.  You saved my life. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

do not archives dSYMs folder open the folder then archives your appname.app.dSYMs then sumbit it

and use Debug Information Format DWARF with dSYM File in debug if you what crash report in debug

Answer (score 0):

If you are not generated the dSYMs file then go :

Organizer in Xcode.
Chose right version which is uploaded on the iTunes, right click on that versions shows option Package contents.
Go to dSYMs folder and select .dSYM file upload it on the Fabric then you get the crash reports.
More details on this link >>>>> https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-dsym

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Another very important steps; click "Download Debug Symbols". I found the missing UUID after doing this step.

Answer (score 0):

The official guide to solve "Missing dSYM" issue has been published by firebase : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?authuser=0

Copying the content of link below for quick reference.

> Firebase Crashlytics automatically processes your debug symbol (.dSYM)
>   files to give you deobfuscated, human-readable crash reports.
>
> Unfortunately, there are a few situations when dSYM uploads fail,
>   usually because of unique project configurations or Bitcode in your
>   app. When an upload fails, Crashlytics displays a "Missing dSYM" alert
>   in the Firebase console to let you know that it can't display crash
>   reports properly.
>
> If you get that alert, there are two things you can try to resolve the
>   issue: check that Xcode is producing the correct dSYM files and, if it
>   is, run the dSYM upload script manually.
>
> **Check if Xcode is producing debug symbol files**
>
> More often than not, symbol files go missing because Xcode simply
>   isn't producing them. Here's how to check if your project is
>   generating dSYMs with every build:
>
> Open your project in Xcode, and select the project file in the Xcode
>   Navigator. Select your main build target from the Select a project or
>   target dropdown. Open the target's Build Settings tab. Click All near
>   the top of the tab. Search for "debug information format". Set Debug
>   Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File. Once you've done that,
>   build your app again and check the Firebase console to see if
>   Crashlytics can find your dSYMs.
>
> **Run the upload symbols script manually**
>
> As a back-up, Crashlytics also includes upload-symbols, a script that you can call anywhere in
>   your build process to upload your dSYMs manually. The script provides
>   more information about the upload process and more robust error
>   messaging.
>
> Important: If you're working with an app that you previously linked
>   from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, pass in your Fabric API Key to
>   run the upload symbols script. That is, in the following options to
>   run the script, use -a fabric-api-key instead of -gsp
>   path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist. To run the upload-symbols script,
>   use one of the following options:
>
> Include the following line in your build process:

```
find dSYM_directory -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} $PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p platform \{\}
```

> Run the script directly from your terminal:

```
/path/to/pods/directory/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

> Run the script from an Xcode run script build phase:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

> Note: If you're having trouble, run upload-symbols without any
>   parameters to get usage notes and additional instructions.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue with fabric crashlytics.
Then I created ipa with distribution profile and installed it via itunes to my device.I started receiving crash reports after it.Hope it helps :)