# Crashlytics does not show crashes

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics

I have just installed Crashlitycs using [this](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) official instruction.

I have set Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release and disabled Bitcode (some people wrote that it could help):

[image]

AppDelegate:

```
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

To simulate a crash I use

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

and

```
var ggg: Int!
print(ggg)
```

Crashlitics collects some information about sessions. For example it updates bundle versions info:

[image]

So connection with Crashlitics works. However crash information is empty:

[image]

I am using XCode 8 and iOS 9/10. What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have tested it on simulator and device without XCode debugger connection (i.e. launching from sumulator/device screen)

Finally I have received some Crashlytics reports after 7-8 hours after crashes. I expected them earlier because according to [documentation](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features):

> Within a few minutes, you should see the crash appear on your Fabric
>   Dashboard.

However I did not receive all crashes I was waiting for. During my experiments I have tried different ways to initialise Crashlytics:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
and
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])
```

Could it be the reason? I have also found the similar unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723308/how-to-init-fabric-properly-in-swift).

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you testing with Xcode's debugger connected?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I was testing without XCode debugger connected. I have also updated the question. Could you check it please?

Comment: If you hit run in Xcode, then the debugger will be automatically connected. You would need to explicitly hit Stop in Xcode, then launch the app from the Simulator without hitting Run.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Sure. This is how I do it - "launching from sumulator/device screen".

Comment: Given the current information, SO, may no longer be the best place to discuss this as it's becoming a conversation. Can you please post on TwitterCommunity.com/c/fabric or email into support(at)fabric(dot)io?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Checked the following terms,

1. Make sure Crashlytics SDK line is after all other 3rd-party SDK lines. (it needs to be last one called in your appDidFinishLaunching method.)
2. Force a crash and then relaunch the app. Xcode must be disconnected to stop it from intercepting the crash report. To disconnect Xcode, follow the instructions [here](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-).
3. If you're using [Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; to test crashing, make sure it's not in the appDidFinishLaunching method.

These are already mentioned in support section, Here is additional ones -

1. Check in organization -> Your App -> Missing dSYM, Is it showing any missing dSYM file

[image]

if yes, Then do the following step

1. Right Click on your archive -> Show in Finder -> Right click on file and click on Show package contents
2. Right click on dSYM file - > Show package contents -> Contents -> Resources -> DWARF (Open in terminal)
3. Run command dwarfdump --uuid "file name you saw there in dwarf folder"

[image]

This will show all the associated UUID, And if any listed UUID matched with the one mentioned in missing dSYM id then just compress the dSYM folder and upload it on crashlytics Missing dSYM segment.

This step is important cause sometimes the dSYM file we extract from organizer doesn't contain correct UUID. And after uploading the wrong one we wait for its updations. So it's better to make sure you are uploading the right dSYM file.

Other than aforementioned things, Bitcode property and Debug Information Format in Build Settings also affect the crash reporting.

Comment: Perfect answer !

Comment: Even non fatal errors require the Xcode debugger to be disconnected.

Answer (score 11):

You need to run the app but not from Xcode.

If you are using a device, just launch the app without usb connected.
If you are using simulator, stop the running of the app from Xcode. Then open it again via mouse click instead.

Next, navigate to the `buttonPress` or `function` that will call the `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`.

Then **reopen** the app again after crash.(This could be connected to console if you want) This step is important because crashlytics save the crash report just before the app is terminated. The next time you open the app, it will then post the report up to crashlytics.

The docs [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html) actually explain the troubleshooting issue as well.

Comment: I have already did it this way. I wrote about it in "EDIT" section. However I do not unplug usb when testing in device (but launching app from device, not XCode). Do you think it could be critical?

Answer (score 5):

Double-check in your Build Settings that your Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the second sentence, the OP says 'I have set Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release...'? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: This is answer of my problem. I didnt realize this before. Thanks a lot, you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Another potential cause of crashes not uploading is implementing the Crashlytics delegate without calling the completion handler:

```
// MARK: CrashlyitcsDelegate
func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // Last launch we crashed!
    }
}
```

Instead, it should look like this:

```
// MARK: CrashlyitcsDelegate
func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // Last launch we crashed!
         completionHandler(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still relevant in 2019.

Just like [Zac Kwan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539131/zac-kwan) said, you have to do this without your app instance attached to Xcode.

If you're following [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?authuser=0) docs, they make you understand it as, you add the needed information, then to test, press the crash button, then relaunch, all via Xcode.

Do the following:

1. Add the needed Crashlytics information to your project. Run it in Xcode once. Then go ahead and manually go to your simulator, open your app, force the crash.
2. You should get an email about a "Fatal Error".
3. About 5-10 minutes later, it will show in your Firebase console.