# Crashalytics mail is not coming

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have setup everything Crashalytics mail is not coming [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH7ar.png)

Comment: Please check my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856414/crashlytics-does-not-show-crashes/40037060#40037060). Hope it will help. :)

Comment: Sometimes Crashalytics takes a lot of time to send report, It happened with me twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added following code in AppDelegate Class. Try this

```
[CrashlyticsKit setUserIdentifier:@"12345"]; // Default
[CrashlyticsKit setUserEmail:@"Enter your email address"];//user@fabric.io
[CrashlyticsKit setUserName:@"Test User"];// Default
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have completed the setup by following the [documentation](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install), then the mail might not be coming because you have to setup a developer account for that purpose and have a **iOS developer certificate** in your Xcode provisioning profile